# How to create a second component on react using the data from the API and create a dynamic URL

Tags: reactjs, react-router, components, state

I have a component showing the list of blogpost and I create a URL for every post coming from the title, into a string and then split and joint, but I need to create a second component that render the page of the blogpost itself,
my question is, is there any way to pass the state or props from the already created list component into the blogpost component and be access only by that rout URL?

this is the blogdata component that i wanted to use to transfer the state to the other components but only one is working, fetching the data from the API into this.state.blogpost

```
class BlogData extends Component{
   state = {
        blogData: []        
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get(`data.json`)
          .then(res => {      
            const blogData = [res.data.blogPosts]       ;
            this.setState({blogData});                        
          })          
    };
    render(){
        const blogData = this.state.blogData.map((value) =>
            value.map((val, idx) =>                                                       
                <BlogBlock 
                    link={val.title.toString().toLowerCase().split(" ").join("-")} 
                    title={val.title}
                    subtitle={val.subtitle}
                    thumb={val.thumb}
                    idx={idx}
                />

            )
        )            
        return( 
            <section id="blog" className="blogList">
                <h2>From the Blog</h2>
                <div className="blogPosts">   
                    {blogData}              
                </div>            
            </section>
        )
    }    
}

const BlogBlock = (props) => {                
    return (
        <div className={`blog-post post-${props.idx}`}>
            <Link to={props.link}>
                <Img loader={<span className="loading-img">loading....</span>} src={`http://brittdepetter.com/images/${props.thumb}`} alt={props.title} />
                <h3>{props.title}<span><br />{props.subtitle}</span></h3>
            </Link>  
        </div>                        
    )   
}
```

and the component that im trying to create but not working is this one, but no lock of making the route works :(

```
const BlogPost = (props) => {                                         
    return (                                           
        <div>    
            <Router path={props.link} />            
            <Title title={props.title } />                                             
            <div className="textBox boxImg">
                <div className="story-img-box">
                    <Img src={props.imgsrc } />                            
                </div>            
                <div>
                   <Paragraph body={props.body} />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>                                
    )   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is way to pass a extra parameter on Link. For that you should pass `to` attribute as object instead of string.
change your Link

```
<Link to={props.link}>
```

to

```
<Link to={{pathname:props.link, blog:props}}>
```

In your BlogPost component, access using following code

```
this.props.location.blog
```

PS. refreshing browser while you are on BlogPost component will require to re-fetch a blog again.